# Viewing uploaded documents(pdf, .doc, .xls, etc.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, download

I have a simple program were users can create, show and edit projects. One of the features of the projects is file upload. I have experimented with several different methods of uploading the files including carrierwave and paperclip. The problem I am having is that I need users to be able to view the files that are uploaded. Ex: open pdfs or excel spreadsheets that other user have uploaded to that project. I am new to rails and have no idea how to do this. All i can find are tutorials on how to upload and show pictures. Does anyone know how I can do this? I have looked at send_data and send_file but cannot figure out if I should use these or how to implement them. Thanks in advance

I'm using rails 3.0.10 and ruby 1.8.7 on an Ubuntu server

Comment: What do you think about using google doc api ?

Comment: Why can't you figure out if you should use them? Doesn't `send_file` do precisely what you want? Implementing them is... pretty simple; there are [examples in the apidock docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file).